# Is there the mistake in the next sentence?

Tags: grammar

> It is the next best thing to having an actual qualified teacher facilitate your practice session

I'm embarrassing with the phrase "to having". This is incorrect in according to Grammar. One can find a lot of similar examples on the web, e.g.:

> We are so close to having our family.
>
> The Government has expressed its commitment to having the Statute ratified.

Usually, we use either to + V or Ving. How to explain such a construction?

Comment: When you say "How to explain such a construction", what are you looking for, and what have you found so far?

Comment: I just want to understand, is this phrase correct or not. In my Grammar book, I haven't found any mentions of "to having" phrase. Why do people use this such way?

Comment: It works in the context you provided. I wouldn’t say that grammar prohibits it. But *why* people use it is probably too broad for this site. That sounds more like a question of psychology than of language.

Comment: The phrase is not "to having", it's " to having an actual qualified teacher facilitate your practice session".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write: *Usually, we use either _to + V_ or _Ving_.*

This is true about clauses with [catenative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs) verbs. Some of these are followed by one form only, while others can take both forms:

> - I want to play chess.
> - I enjoy playing chess.
> - I like to play chess. I like playing chess.

None of your examples, which are all correct, contains a catenative verb. Sentences 1 and 3 contain nouns (*thing* and *commitment*) followed by the *to + Ving* form. Sentence 2 contains an adjective (*close*) followed by this form.

However, the same principle applies to nouns and adjectives as to catenative verbs: You need learn word by word how the complement is constructed.

Nouns, for example:

> - the desire to have big family
> - pride in having a big car
> - an apology for having an affair

Adjectives:

> - afraid to have a baby - afraid of having a baby
> - proud of having a big car car - proud to have a big car
> - sorry to be late - sorry for being late

Comment: As I understand, those examples contain "noun/adj + preposition" form. The form "Noun/Adj + preposition" describes the specific meaning and always stands together. To complete idea, we just use preposition phrase, where Ving sometime follows as in my examples ("the best thing to having teacher"). The same way we can complete the meaning another way, i.e. "the best thing to I can come".